# Método Remove não funciona, nem retorna erro

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Meu método `remove` não apaga o registro no *BD*. E, o pior, retorna nenhum erro, nem executa a *query* (exceto pelos *Select*, creio que seja normal).

Usei os *prints* para saber se o objeto estava chegando do `Controller` para o `Repository`, bem como se o `find` no banco foi bem-sucedido e, sim, tudo *ok* até aí.

Onde estou errando?

**AlunosRepository.java**

```
public void apagar(Long id) {
      try {
      Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
      System.out.print("Meu ID: " + id);
      // Busca a pessoa na base de dados através do seu ID.
      aluno = manager.find(Aluno.class, id);
      System.out.print(aluno.getNomeAluno());
      // Remove a pessoa da base de dados.
      manager.remove(aluno);
      } catch (Exception e) {

      }
```

**GerenciamentoAlunoBean.java**

```
public void deletar() {
    alunosRepository.apagar(alunoSelecionado.getId());
    alunoSelecionado = null;

}
```

**Aluno.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "aluno")
public class Aluno {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String nomeAluno;

    @NotEmpty
    @CPF
    private String cpf;

    @NotNull
    private Integer numMatricula;

    @NotEmpty
    private String telefone;

    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    private String curso;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "data_nascimento")
    private Date dataNascimento;

    @OneToOne 
    private Endereco endereco;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNomeAluno() {
        return nomeAluno;
    }

    public void setNomeAluno(String nomeAluno) {
        this.nomeAluno = nomeAluno;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public Integer getNumMatricula() {
        return numMatricula;
    }

    public void setNumMatricula(Integer numMatricula) {
        this.numMatricula = numMatricula;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }

    public void setDataNascimento(Date dataNascimento) {
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }

    public String getCurso() {
        return curso;
    }

    public void setCurso(String curso) {
        this.curso = curso;
    }

    public Endereco getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Aluno other = (Aluno) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Endereco.java**

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "endereco") 
public class Endereco {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String logradouro;

    @NotEmpty
    private String bairro;

    @NotEmpty
    private String cep;

    @NotEmpty
    private String complemento;

    @NotEmpty
    private String cidade;

    @NotEmpty
    private String uf;

    @OneToOne (mappedBy = "endereco", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Aluno aluno;

    @OneToOne (mappedBy = "endereco", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Professor professor;

    @OneToOne (mappedBy = "endereco", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Coordenador coordenador;

    public Professor getProfessor() {
        return professor;
    }

    public void setProfessor(Professor professor) {
        this.professor = professor;
    }

    public Coordenador getCoordenador() {
        return coordenador;
    }

    public void setCoordenador(Coordenador coordenador) {
        this.coordenador = coordenador;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogradouro() {
        return logradouro;
    }

    public void setLogradouro(String logradouro) {
        this.logradouro = logradouro;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getComplemento() {
        return complemento;
    }

    public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
        this.complemento = complemento;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getUf() {
        return uf;
    }

    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }

    public Aluno getAluno() {
        return aluno;
    }

    public void setAluno(Aluno aluno) {
        this.aluno = aluno;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Endereco other = (Endereco) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você tem um try-catch vazio no `AlunosRepository`. Como garante que não está estourando nenhum erro?

Comment: Na verdade, ele retorna sim um erro, porem você não esta fazendo nada com ele, e como o Pedro disse, o seu catch esta vazio, coloque um system.out.println(e); e atualize sua pergunta com o erro retornado.

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado, senhores. Fiz exatamente como o @LuisEduardo orientou, todavia nada foi apresentado no console. Seria um problema de relacionamento? Algo a ver com OneToOne? Estou editando para adicionar a camada Endereco.

Comment: Sim, tem a ver, se você esta tentando deletar um conteúdo de uma tabela pai, e esse conteúdo possui filhos e você não definiu cascade no seu model pai, além de não remover o conteúdo desejado, ele retorna um erro, que no seu caso creio que seja justamente isso.

Answer (score 0):

Passei pelo mesmo problema, o que fiz foi basicamente retornar o objeto pelo find, depois dar merge e commit neste.

```
private final static EntityManager manager = ConnectionFactory.getEntityManager();

public T findById2(Class<T> clazz, Long id) {
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    return manager.find(clazz, id);
}

public void remove(T t) {
    manager.merge(t);
    manager.remove(t);
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```